# google maps v3 street view with user photos

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In v2 of google maps streetview I can show user photos like here:
[panoramio](http://blog.panoramio.com/2009/02/explore-more-with-user-photos-in-street.html), how to enable or add this feature in google maps v3?

Answer (score 1):

Using google map api v3 u can do user photos in streetview. Check the following link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewPanoramas

Comment: I added streetViewControl: true for second map(small right), but in the above map (big street view) the images not showing :(
http://www.earth-dots.de/jahrestreffen-der-trilateralen-kommission-im-kempinski-270665.html

Comment: Check the following link, Here both street view and image view is there. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple